# How to detect word suggestion bar on top of keyboard is showed or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I am developing a chat app and i found a problem when keyboard appear method. I am using UIKeyboardDidShowNotification to move my chat textview and button on top of the keyboard. But my chat textview is hidden by word sugesstion tool bar when showing word suggestion or changing keyboard to other language like Japanese. Keyboard height got by UIKeyboardNotification is late. And so, how to detect that suggestion toolbar is shown or not?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect rectTable = rTable;
    rectTable.origin.y -= kbSize.height;
    CGRect rectToolBar = rToolbar;
    rectToolBar.origin.y -= kbSize.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                     animations:^{
                         [self.tableView setFrame:rectTable];
                         [self.toolBar setFrame:rectToolBar];
                     }
    ];
}
```

If changing textview location doen't work, is there another way to put textview on top of the keyboard?

Comment: any code part you wrote, post it here. It will help?

Comment: i update with the code.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using this,

```
CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

try this

```
CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a condition that if user typed text is in first line, then set `[textview setScrollEnabled:NO]` else set `YES`.

Comment: I don't want to do that way. Just want to place textview at the top of  suggesstion word bar of the keyboard.

Comment: are you displaying suggestions in seperate uiview?

Comment: no, the word sugesstion bar when type with the japanese keyboard.

Comment: sorry i didnt used japanese keyboard . Can you make your Ques clear?